# What is the physical limit of thermal insulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, heat-conduction

If we consider a container (at very low) temperature $T_0$ surrounded by some *passive* structure, in turn surrounded by an environment at temperature $T_1>T_0$, there will be an inward heat flow leaking through the structure. What is the physical limit of minimal heat leakage? Or, conversely, what is the limiting thermal insulation structure?

**Insulation**

An obvious choice of the structure is some insulating material. In this case the flow is $$q \approx kA_0\frac{T_1-T_0}{d}$$ where $k$ is the thermal conductivity, $A_0$ the area of the inner compartment, and $d$ the thickness (this ignores geometric effects, hence the approximation). [Under standard conditions silica aerogel and polyurethane foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities) reaches 0.020 W/Km, but most of that is air thermal conductivity. By reducing pressure it can be reduced: at $10^{-7}$ atmospheres it is down to 0.000012 W/Km.

(The thermal conductivity $k$ of metals is temperature dependent as $k=k_0T$ at low temperature, so the formula above needs to be adjusted a bit. I will ignore this as follows, but it is worth noting. Also, a pre-cooled insulator can hence get lower conductivity; however this will not be stable as ambient heat diffuses in and changes it and the thermal capacity. Again, I will ignore this time-dependent nonlinearity since it does not appear to dominate over radiation.)

**Radiation**

Were we to instead just have a perfect vacuum between the container and environment they would couple by blackbody radiation. The flow would be $$q=\epsilon A_0\sigma (T_1^4-T_0^4)$$
where $\epsilon$ is the emissivity and $\sigma$ the Stefan-Boltzman constant. There is no dependency on $d$ since the container only "sees" the environment in all directions. [The minimum emissivity in standard tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_emissivity) is polished silver, 0.02.

If we for example assume $A_0=1$ m$^2$, $T_0=10^{-29}$ K, $T_1=3$ K then using $10^{-7}$ atm air insulation the flow is $q=3.6\cdot 10^{-5}/d$ Watts. Using vacuum and polished silver the flow is $9.186\cdot 10^{-8}$ W. In theory we could get a smaller flow by having a more than 391 meter thick insulation, but this implicitly presupposes that the entire mass of insulation has been cooled to an appropriate temperature beforehand.

**Edit**: There is [multi-layer insulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-layer_insulation) that can reduce the thermal flow even in the radiative case. If we insert $N$ layers the heat transfer coefficient will be $4\sigma T^3/(N(2/\epsilon - 1)+1)$, which can be made arbitrarily small by increasing $N$.

The limit of the number of layers is when the distance become a few wavelengths since near-field effects will start coupling them. From the Wien displacement law we get $\lambda=b/T$, so for 3K this $\lambda \approx 1$ mm, while down at $T=10^{-29}$ K $\lambda\approx 9$ Gpc. For a given $d$ the number of layers that can fit in scales as $d^{3/4}$.

**Discussion**

So, refining the question a bit to avoid "cheating" by having infinitely thick pre-cooled insulation: for a fixed $d$, what sets the physical limit of heat flow? For conduction there are clearly [many physical effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity#Physical_origins), but getting rid of the material gets rid of the phonons, only leaving photon modes in blackbody radiation. Other fields are too short-range to matter or couple too weakly (there is presumably some gravitational wave heat transfer, but it is vastly overshadowed by the electromagnetic contribution).

Closely related sub-questions: Is there any principle that gives a lower bound on emissivity? Does quantization effects hinder radiative heat transfer at *very* low temperatures (I am interested in the $\sim 10^{-29}$ K range)? Is there some thermodynamic principle that implies that the heat flow *must* be nonzero?

Comment: I have used either [this multilayered insulation](http://www.lydallpm.com/products/low-temperature-insulation/crs-wrap-super-insulating-media/overview/) or a very similar product. The data sheet claims a hard vacuum limit of a few microwatts per meter per kelvin at a mean temperature of 80K.

Comment: Did you intend to type $10^{-29}$ kelvin? The record low temperatures achieved with microscopic masses of Bose-Einstein condensates are many orders of magnitude warmer than this. Macroscopic passive insulation probably stops being important around the microkelvin range; the isolation of the dilute gas that makes the condensate uses a very different method.

Comment: @rob - Yes, the temperature is intentional. It is around the de Sitter temperature of the universe. In my research, I am interested in extreme low-temperature physics of the far future.